# IPv6 automatically gets disabled after every second reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, ipv6

I'm trying to set a static IPv6 address on Windows 7 and I connect just fine. But after 2 reboots (not one), it disappears.

After much troubleshooting, I also see the *DisabledComponents* reg key reappear with `ffffffff` entered as the value. I have tried deleting this key and changing the value to 0. I can and it's fine after 1 reboot, but reverts after 2 reboots.

The key is in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters`

I suspect a GPO policy setting may be the culprit and is overriding this reg key after 2 reboots. I am unable to pinpoint which setting or if this is the issue at all.

I have done all this:

```
netsh interface IPv6 set global randomizeidentifier=disabled
netsh interface IPv6 set privacy state=disable
netsh interface IPv6 6to4 set state state=disabled
netsh interface IPv6 isatap set state state=disabled
netsh interface IPv6 set teredo=disable
```

also Teredo, Isatap, etc. are all set to Enabled - Set to Disabled in the GPO in ComputerConfiguration\AdminstrativeTemplates\Network\TCPIP\IPV6 Transition Technologies.

Google is loaded with information on how to disable IPv6, which is what let me to this reg key, but there is not much on what all to set/reset to reenable IPv6 if it's not working.

Comment: do you use a "tweaking" tool under Windows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "tweaking tool," but i think the answer is no.